# How does Caja file manager store the emblems I have attached to files?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, mate, caja

I'm preparing a complete re-install (from Mint MATE to Ubuntu MATE), and am trying to capture as much as possible of my current setup.

One thing I haven't been able to find via Google is,

- How can I backup/restore/salvage the *emblems* that I have attached to many files and folders?
- How are these even stored in the first place (there are no hidden files for it as far as I can see)?

I'm using these extensively, and they do provide value to my work, so doing without them would be a loss. However, manually noting everything down and then manually re-emblemming (yes, that's a word, now) them would be both very cumbersome and guaranteed error-prone.

Answer (score 2):

Caja (and older versions of Nautilus) will use the gvfs-metadata backend to store emblem metadata. You can query the emblem values of files/folders using the GIO CLI utility (`gio info <path_to_file_or_folder>`) - values will be stored under metadata::emblems. You can also set values for this attribute by using `gio set -t stringv <path_to_file_or_folder> metadata::emblems <emblem1> <emblem2> ...`

If you're wondering why nobody has bothered to automate this process so far, I don't really know either, but I've put together a simple python3 script to export/import emblems using JSON files. If anyone ever needs it, you can find it here: https://github.com/WinterSnowfall/emblem_exporter